# Given a public key, is it possible to create a challenge that would produce a known signature, if signed by the corresponding private key?

Tags: signature, encryption, hardware-wallets

Noob alert!

Since hardware wallets don't support decryptWithPrivateKey function, I would like to make a workaround using signatures
If it's possible to create the challenge, that would produce a pre-determined output only when signed by particular private key, I could encrypt the message with this pre-determined output, and then send the challenge together with the encrypted message to the recepient

I wonder whether it's possible